# Why won't my <span> center vertically?

Tags: html, css

I've tried everything, but it seems like this span just won't do anything I tell it to. No applied properties change its vertical position, but horizontal properties do.

I've followed all the recommendations from this guide: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Code:

```css
#header{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100% - 50px;
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
    background-color: #00A680;
}

#header-right-icon-div > img{
    height: 20px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}

#menu-join-button{
    
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-right" style="float: right;">
           <div id="header-right-icon-div">
               
               <img src="briefcase_icon.svg" alt="">
               
               <img src="notification_icon.svg" alt="">
               
               <img src="profile_icon.svg" alt="">
               
               <img src="search_icon.svg" alt="">
               
               <span id="menu-join-button">hello</span>
               
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Even top or bottom margins and padding don't affect it at all... but side margins do...

What is the issue here, why does this `menu-join-button` have a mind of it's own? How do I center the span in that green header?

Comment: Side note, this is incorrect `width: 100% - 50px;`. Probably want a `calc` in there. You also said you "tried everything" yet I see nothing that you tried in terms of positioning the span.

Comment: That's because I deleted it because none of it worked. I tried line-height, margin, padding, text-align.

Comment: The line-height method [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/exgnudj7/)

Comment: Looks centered in your example to me? What am I missing?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda, it only centers when the SVGs are NOT visible. When I delete all the imgs, the text is centered.

Answer (score 1):

**Verticle align middle Way:**

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header{

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
    background-color: #00A680;
}
#header:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#header-right{
     float:right;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    background-color: #00A680;
}

#header-right-icon-div > img{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#menu-join-button{

}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<div id="header-right">
           <div id="header-right-icon-div">
               
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="">
               
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="">
               
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="">
               
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="">
               
               <span id="menu-join-button">hello</span>
               
           </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**Flex Way:**

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
    background-color: #00A680;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items:center;
}

#header-right{
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    background-color: #00A680;
 
}
#header-right-icon-div {
   display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}
#header-right-icon-div > img{
   padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<div id="header-right">
           <div id="header-right-icon-div">
               
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="">
               
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="">
               
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="">
               
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="">
               
               <span id="menu-join-button">hello</span>
               
           </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But one question, why does the `<span>` get centered when `vertical-align: middle` is applied to the img?

Comment: @J.Doe actually you need to `vertical-align: middle` img because default image `vertical-align` is `baseline` to font

Comment: but why does that affect the proceeding <span>? Shouldn't the <span> only be affected by its own `vertical-align`?

Comment: technically your span has no verticle-align property by default but the image has and it set `vertical-align:baseline` by default so you only need to change the image. span verticle-align has no effect.